# How to get execution context of a child Notebook from a parent Notebook in Databricks

Tags: databricks

I am trying to execute a few notebooks in loop from a single notebook using the dbutils.notebook.run. I want to capture the execution context details of the child notebooks like runID and jobID for logging purpose.

I tried using dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDButils().notebook().getContext() but that only gets me the details of the parent notebook. I am unable to figure how to associate the run of the child notebooks to the getContext or how to get the data for the child notebooks. Can somebody help me with this please?